Vite and three js web app deployed on vercel is not redirecting to other page
I have created a web app to explore solar system which consists of two pages

Which shows the main solar system and how it works
Which gives you the experience of 3D model of each planet

And when I try to access the second page it doesn't redirect but stays on the same page and reloads it and url is changed or it shows this:

error -404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND ID: bom1:bom1::zqx2z-1728391679444-2646df531e05

I have deployed my website using vercel in which I have used d3.js and vite and I have defined vite as framework in my project settings in vercel.
Here is the website link - https://solar-expo-six.vercel.app/
Here is my GitHub repo - https://github.com/y8done/solar_expo

You haven't really provided enough detail in your question to answer.  I looked briefly at your site (cool project) and can see that the JS redirect to 3dmodel.html?planet=earth (for example) is happening.  But it looks like the index.html page is the handler for it.  I don't know anything about vercel but this looks like it redirects everything back to / which is index.html.   What are you expecting to happen?

after I redirect to 3dmodel.html by retrieving the planet name I want to display the 3d model of that planet using javascript that you can check on my GitHub the model are in glb and some use textures and sphere geometry (btw thankf for replying )
